# Why can't shutdown my pc with getopts function?

Tags: bash

It is verified that `sudo shutdown -P` can shutdown my pc.

```
test(){
while getopts   "s"  arg
do 
case $arg in 
s)
    sudo shutdown -P 
    ;;
esac
done
}
```

Why `test -s` can't shutdown my pc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't name your own shell function (or program) `test`. It is at least confusing (and makes your script unreadable), since `test` is a POSIX command (see [test(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html), also typed as `[` ....) and a bash (& bourne shell) [builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins).

I guess that by renaming your function as `test_shutdown` it should work.